# tf.concat giving 'Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1' error even if both tensors are the same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to concat two tensorflow constants of the same shape but I'm getting an error. Here's the code. (I just edited it to make the init value explicit)

import tensorflow as tf

```
b1 = tf.constant(value=[5,8])
b2 = tf.constant(value=[6,9])
b3= tf.concat( [b1, b2] , 1) 

with tf.Session( ) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([ b3] ))
```

Gives this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1658   try:
-> 1659     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1660   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'stack_38' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [2,2], [2].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-3acc40ce0738> in <module>()
      1 c1 = [[5,8], [7,4]]
      2 c2 = [6,9]
----> 3 c3= tf.stack( [c1, c2] )
      4 with tf.Session( ) as sess:
      5     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    179     try:
--> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in stack(values, axis, name)
   1003                                                       expanded_num_dims))
   1004 
-> 1005   return gen_array_ops.pack(values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1006 
   1007 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in pack(values, axis, name)
   5446   axis = _execute.make_int(axis, "axis")
   5447   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 5448         "Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   5449   _result = _op.outputs[:]
   5450   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    786         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    787                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 788                          op_def=op_def)
    789       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    790 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    499                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    500                 instructions)
--> 501       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    502 
    503     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(***failed resolving arguments***)
   3298           input_types=input_types,
   3299           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3300           op_def=op_def)
   3301       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3302     return ret

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1821           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1822       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1823                                 control_input_ops)
   1824 
   1825     # Initialize self._outputs.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1660   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1661     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1662     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1663 
   1664   return c_op

ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'stack_38' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [2,2], [2].
```

Even though the two tensors are exactly the same shape. If I do axis=0 it works, and if I replace the tensors with regular numpy arrays of the same numbers, it works, but some how the combination of tensorflow constants and axis=1 is causing an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I'm a little confused as to your issue, but the 0th axis dimension of the two tensors must be the same in order to concatenate along the 1st axis.  What does making b1 have shape [6,8] or b2 have shape [5,9] do?  Either of those cases should result in a successful concatenation.</strike>

Edited because I misread the script the first time.  As I commented, you can't concatenate on the 1st axis because your tensors are rank 1 (they have only an axis 0, or rather they only have 1 dimension).  If they were rank 2 (requiring two dimensions to describe the shape), then you could concatenate on the 1st axis without issue.

For example, you could concatenate tensor([[5,8]]) and tensor([[6,9]]) across axis=1, because they have shapes [1,2] instead of just shapes [2].

Comment: I thought [6,8]  [5,9] would be the initial values, not the shape of the tensor? I changed the code to explicitly specify that those are the values and not the shape, but still getting an error, though the error is different now. I updated my post with the new code and error.

Comment: Derp.  I saw those as a function like tf.ones for whatever reason, my apologies.  Rereading your question, you can't concatenate on axis 1 because your arrays have a dimension of 1, and axis=1 gets concat to smush the tensors together on the second dimension.

For example:  tensor([6,8]) has shape [2], though tensor([[6,8]]) has shape [1,2]

Comment: just tried `b1 = tf.constant(value=[[5,8]])
b2 = tf.constant(value=[[6,9]])
b3= tf.concat( [b1, b2] , 0) ` and got result I'm looking for. Thanks